# Pity task, but I can't solve it

Tags: python

I a really 1st level ninja and want to solve my homework, but I can't it:

So the task is:

> Saying a number between 1-100 :
>   I say 15
>   Okey, that's good
>   Saying a number between 1-100 :
>   I say 231
>   Grrr, bad answer, say another number
>   I say -58
>   Grrr, bad answer, say another number
>   78
>   Okey, that's good
>   Saying a number between 1-100 :

That's my problem cause of I can write a code to the first line, but I can't to step forward

my code is:

```
x=input("Saying a number between 1-100: ")
print(x)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What code have you got? What is the question? Please try asking your question clearer, and remember that we will help you solve problems, but not do your homework. That's why it's homework. For more information on how to ask questions, please visit the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) Thanks. :)

Comment: @user2372684 which version of Python are you actually using? You tagged two different versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will not give you the full answer because this is homework, but anyway I will try to set you in the right direction:

1. You need to **loop** and repeat the action of reading and checking input number for an **indefinite number of times**.
2. There is a **choice**, based on the value of `x`. Some values will lead to `print("OK!")`, some others to `print("Grr")`.
3. Your choice involves **comparing numbers**, but `input` will give you a **string**. You will have to convert it.